# ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional Ann model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

```
# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
model.fit(X_train, y_train ,batch_size = 5, epochs = 10, verbose=0)

# Generating Predictions on testing data
Predictions=model.predict(X_test)

# Scaling the predicted data back to original scale
Predictions=TargetVarScalerFit.inverse_transform(Predictions)

# Scaling the y_test data back to original scale
y_test_orig=TargetVarScalerFit.inverse_transform(y_test)

# Scaling the test data back to original scale
Test_Data=PredictorScalerFit.inverse_transform(X_test)
TestingData=pd.DataFrame(data=Test_Data , columns=Predictors)
```

i have an error message showed below as pics. Could anyone help me fix this problem? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like you're trying to assign `TestingData`'s column names to `Predictors`, that is either a DataFrame or another kind of multidimensional object, and which I don't seem to find anywhere else in your code. Was it some column from `Predictors` you meant or was it `Predictions`? Check them out first.

Comment: it should be the column from Predictors